# Decrease network traffic by adding another router

Tags: home-networking

I have an old laptop that I use as a media server. It is connected to my router via LAN cable as is my smart TV.

I notice that when I'm streaming video on the TV from the laptop, other devices experience slow or no internet connectivity over Wi-Fi. I tried set up the media server laptop to be it’s own hotspot but I think the hardware can’t support AP mode.

If I add a second router and plug the TV and the laptop server into it (DHCP disabled on router 2/still handled by router 1) will the traffic between the TV and the laptop (both wired to router 2) stay on router 2 or will it still cause congestion on router 1?

I imagine that the routers would take the shortest path, thus the traffic would stay on router 2 but I’m no network guy. I would still like the devices wired to router 2 to have access to the internet so I would have an open LAN port on router 2 wired to an open LAN port on router 1. Will this fix my congestion? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the router's processor is underpowered/overworked.

> will the traffic between the TV and the laptop (both wired to router 2) stay on router 2

Yes, but you don't even need to use a router.

> Is there a better solution?

Yes.
Since the laptop server and smart TV both use wired Ethernet, all you need to "decrease network traffic" is to add an Ethernet switch (and another UTP cable).  Connect both hosts and the wireless router to a (small, i.e. 5-port) switch, no reconfiguration of anything is necessary, and traffic between those hosts will be isolated from the router.  All of your hosts retain the same connectivity to each other and the Internet.

Almost sounds too good to be true, doesn't it?

Comment: This is what I've been leaning towards

Answer (score 1):

1. If the laptop is using a wired connection then it isn't directly causing WiFi problems (at least not with the WiFi network).
2. At the end of the day, all internet traffic inbound and outbound goes through router 1 so adding router 2 isn't going to solve a problem with router 1 or with your internet connection itself.

Comment: 1. Does it matter that router 1 is also the wireless AP? 2. My high volume streaming traffic isn't going to/from the internet but between devices on my LAN and I only notice issues accessing the internet on other devices while streaming is occurring. If I pause playback, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Flow Control defaults on the NIC

I've always found it better with Flow Control disabled, but try both ways & see which works best.

Assuming Win 7 [it's similar in other Windows]
Control Panel > Network & Internet > Network Connections.
Right click your NIC, Properties, then Configure

[image]

Comment: What's the Linux equivalent?

Comment: I've no idea, sorry. Closest I get to nix is my gateway/UTM, but that's a web interface & I can't get at the NICs directly.